# How long would it take this Curse of Strahd NPC to take over a town?

Tags: dnd-5e, npc, time, curse-of-strahd

I am running the Curse of Strahd campaign, for 5e Dungeons & Dragons.

> Kasimir has taken the dark gift to become immortal, and has killed his closest friend, drinking his blood, becoming a vampire. While the players are away (they do not know he is a vampire), I would love him to seize control of Vallaki. (The burgomaster is already dead, and Lady Wachter was, with her cultists, in a sort of control over the town.)
>
>  I would very much like the characters to come back to the town controlled by Kasimir, with Lady Wachter held captive as his prize.

The question is, how long would it logically take for him to be able to do this?

I guess a logical subquestion would be, how many vampire spawn can a new vampire create each night?

Comment: @fejfo Just so you know, we cover adventure spoilers as a courtesy to others.

Comment: I appreciate that, I am not exactly sure how to do that, I posted this was my first question but this question here, now, is kinda FAR from what I originally posted. Better no doubt, but, very much different. I've got a lot to learn.

Comment: It's typical that questions get “polished” by experienced editors, to put them in their best light. The intent is to keep the question's purpose the same though, and I hope that's been the case here! Is the question still asking what you intended to ask?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I'm just a touch embarrassed at the need for such polishing >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How long do you need it to take?

... and what do you mean by "take over"?

> Nowhere on the map is more than 2 days travel from Vallaki so a sudden takeover has to occur within a few days. However, a slow subtle horrifying take over where every time the player's return things have changed just a little bit for the worse could take weeks or months - this is much more in keeping with the feel of the module.

As to the corollary question: the absolute maximum is 14,400 every 24 hours (24 hours x 60 minutes/hour x 10 rounds/minute = 14,400) assuming the vampire has enough willing workers to bury all the corpses. Practical considerations like moving between victims, dealing with non-helpless victims and wear and tear on the fangs suggest that the actual number would be much lower.